# If I drove pin DP8 high, would the MOSFET Q1 let current pass?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pins

[image]

I have this circuit in my hand.

If I drove pin DP8 high, would the MOSFET Q1 let current pass or would it not let it?
I also have the same question for DP9. What would happen if I drove the pin DP9 high or low via Arduino? This is my first experience with MOSFETs. So I am sorry if I ask something very basic.

Comment: Yes. What have you done to learn how MOSFETs and NPN transistors behave?

Comment: That second 2N222 transistor is confusing me. I know the ones at bottom will let current pass if the pin is low.

Comment: Just asking for clarification as I just finished my project and want to ensure it doesn't burn :D

Comment: *I know the ones at bottom will let current pass if the pin is low* No, that is not the case. You **REALLY** need to study some basics first, start at: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html  "Not burning your circuits" relies on **YOU** understanding how they work and how they should be controlled. If you cannot be bothered, use a motor driver module. Using transistors as switches is **really easy** to understand so I expect some effort from you to understand how the circuit works.

Comment: Remember that I pointed out in your previous question that this circuit is using PMOS and NMOS devices. You turn on the Ps by pulling the gate low. You turn on the Ns by pulling the gate high. Test the circuit with a bench power supply with current limit set to 50 mA or so and increase it if all seems OK.

Comment: THANKS!! It is working now. Now I learned it very well. God bless you all